# Center of Weyl algebra over field $\mathbb{K}$ with positive characteristic $p$: is it $\langle P^p, Q^p \rangle$ or $\mathbb{K}[P^p, Q^p]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to solve a problem (2.7.4) from Etingof, Golberg, Hensel at al.: "Describe the center of the [Weyl] algebra $A$ [over a field $\mathbb{K}$ of char > 0]". The hint is to prove that, if $P$ and $Q$ are the generators (such that $[P, Q]=1$) of Weyl algebra over $\mathbb{K}$ s.t. $\text{char }\mathbb{K}=p$ , then $P^{p}$ and $Q^{p}$ are central. That part, I think, I have done. But I am struggling with determining the rest of the center. [This](https://math.mit.edu/research/undergraduate/spur/documents/2016Zurier.pdf) article suggests that the center is the ideal generated by $P^{p}, Q^{p}$, while [this](http://www.math.kochi-u.ac.jp/docky/preprints/dixmier1.pdf) document states it is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$ over $P^{p},Q^{p}$, so I am confused. I also believe I have proved that the statement about ideal generated by $P^{p}$ and $Q^{p}$ is not true. Take, for instance, the simplest possible case where $p=3$. If the ideal generated by $P^{p}, Q^{p}$ was central, then
$$[QP^{p}, P]$$ would equal zero. However,
$$[QP^{3}, P]=Q[P^{3}, P]+[Q, P]P^{3}=-P^{3}$$
i.e., not zero. If the answer to the question is "the ideal generated by $P^{p}, Q^{p}$", what did I miss in the counterexample above? If it is $\mathbb{K}[P^{p}, Q^{p}]$, how do I prove there are no other central elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centre is always a subring, not an ideal. You have shown that the centre contains $Z=K[P^p,Q^p]$. To show that there is nothing else, we first observe that $W$ is a free $Z$-module of rank $p^2$, with basis $P^aQ^b$ for $0\leq a,b<p$.

Take a central element $c=\sum z_{ab}P^aQ^b$ with $z_{ab}\in Z$. Using $zP=Pz$, we can compare coefficients, using that $W$ is a free $Z$-module, to get the vanishing of many of the $z_{ab}$. From $zQ=Qz$ we get the vanishing of the remaining coefficients, except $z_{00}$. Thus $c=z_{00}\in Z$.

Comment: By "using that $W$ is a free $Z$-module, get the vanishing of many of the $z_{ab}$", do you mean the following: since $W$ is a free module, and $P^{a}Q^{b}$ is the basis, $$[\sum z_{ab}P^{a}Q^{b},P]=0 \iff \forall a, b: [z_{ab}P^{a}Q^{b}, P]=0 \iff z_{ab}[P^{a}Q^{b},P]+[z_{ab}, P]Q^{a}P^{b}=0 \iff z_{ab}[P^{a}Q^{b}, P]=0$$ and since $a,b<p$, this only happens when $b=0$ or when $z_{ab}, b>0, a>0 = 0$ , and the analogous reasoning for $Q$? If this is correct, thanks a lot, this answers the question! Could you give a hint why the centre is always subring and not an ideal?

Comment: Actually, it is __kinda__ clear why $Q^{a}P^{b}$ is a basis, since from Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem we know that $Q^{a}P^{b}$ for arbitrary nonnegative integer $a,b$ is a basis in Weyl algebra, but if we can only multiply by elements of $\mathbb{K}[P^{p}, Q^{p}]$, say, from the left, why are we always able to obtain any desired element of the form $P^{a'}Q^{b'}$, and it alone, without additional terms of lower degree?

Comment: Consider $p=3$. We have a sum $a+bP+cP^2+dQ+ePQ+fP^2Q+gQ^2+hPQ^2+iP^2Q^2$ with $a,\ldots,i\in Z$. Multiply on the right by $P$ and use $QP=PQ-1$ to write again in this form. For example, the coefficient of $PQ$ will be $d-2h$. This equals the formula given by multiplying on the left by $P$, in which case the coefficient of $PQ$ is just $d$. Thus $h=0$. In fact, this shows that all coefficients except $a,b,c$ are zero. Now do the same with $Q$.

Comment: Such an argument shows that $Z$ is the centre. The centre is always a subring, since we can add and multiply central elements, and they remain central. Also all scalars are central.

Comment: We know (eg PBW) that $P^aQ^b$ form a $K$-basis for $W$. As $P^p,Q^p$ are central, we can move them to the front and write this as (central monomial)x$P^iQ^j$ with $0\leq i,j<p$. So such elements span $W$ as a $Z$-module, the central monomials form a $K$-basis of $Z$, and so we see that we have a free $Z$-module.